# No drawer view found with gravity LEFT error on Clicking menu items in drawerlayout

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, drawerlayout

No drawer view found with gravity LEFT occurs whenever I click on the menu items in the navigation view. I am using a custom App bar. I am using openDrawer and closeDrawer functions. Below I pasting the code please help I am stuck on this for a week.

property.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".views.enforcement.PropertyActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/property_header" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="end">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/property_nav" />


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemBackground="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/color_light_blue"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/color_light_blue"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

property.class

```
   private fun initView() {
        navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        mDrawerLayout =  findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)
        navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
            binding.header.menuIV.setOnClickListener {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the navigation drawer open from the left or the right?

Comment: trying to from the right

Comment: Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to be explicit with closeDrawers() because it is inherently Gravity.START but you are calling Gravity.END.
Instead call:

```
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END) 
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working. The error occurs whenever I click on menu items.

Comment: @PrameshSingh you need to post the logcat failures and I need to see code on the implementation of menu and the header xml file.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1865)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1851)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.close(DrawerLayout.java:1800)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$3.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationUI.java:457)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:217)